# How can I extend Array.prototype.push()?

Tags: javascript, arrays, prototype, array-push

I'm trying to extend the `Array.push` method so that using push will trigger a callback method and then perform the normal array function.

I'm not quite sure how to do this, but here's some code I've been playing with unsuccessfully.

```
arr = [];
arr.push = function(data){

    //callback method goes here

    this = Array.push(data);
    return this.length;
}

arr.push('test');
```

Answer (score 78, accepted):

Since *push* allows more than one element to be pushed, I use the *arguments* variable below to let the real push method have all arguments.

This solution only affects the *arr* variable:

```
arr.push = function () {
    //Do what you want here...
    return Array.prototype.push.apply(this, arguments);
}
```

This solution affects all arrays. I do not recommend that you do that.

```
Array.prototype.push = (function() {
    var original = Array.prototype.push;
    return function() {
        //Do what you want here.
        return original.apply(this, arguments);
    };
})();
```

Comment: My favorite form of function wrapping is to pass Array.prototype.push when you execute your outer function, and accept it in the function as the variable original. It's a little more concise

Comment: @pottedmeat: but it's less readable - remember, programs are not only written for the machine, but for other programmers as well!

Comment: @some Thank you so much for a clear explaination of prototype and not!

Comment: When assigning to `Array.prototype.push`, you have to be **extremely careful** about what goes into the `//Do what you want here` code. If anything in it causes a call to `Array.push()` (even indirectly), you'll crash JavaScript with a stack overflow.

Comment: @TedHopp Noticed the "I do not recommend that you do that."? I meant it. On the bright side, you are at the right site ;)

Comment: I just wanted to reinforce your recommendation message by pointing out how easily severe unpleasantness can arise from ignoring it.

Comment: Great! And how about index-based assignment? Why is there no set(index) or other method, which could raise an event?

Comment: Here's an example of a fiddle that syncs array2 with array1 using this method: https://jsfiddle.net/hhwcteoj/2/.

Comment: What will happen if 2 different scripts implement such a method on the same array? Will both overrides be executed, or only the last one? I think only the last one, so how to ensure you call the previous implementation (overridden or not)?

Comment: @JBHurteaux They will execute one after the other, in the order that they where initialized.

Comment: Update to @TedHopp's point: In modern browsers it'll just throw an error for the maximum call stack size being exceeded, which doesn't result in anything particularly nasty.

Answer (score 11):

First you need subclass `Array`:

ES6 (https://kangax.github.io/compat-table/es6/):

```
class SortedArray extends Array {
    constructor(...args) {
        super(...args);
    }
    push() {
        return super.push(arguments);
    }
}
```

ES5 (**proto** is almost deprecated, but it is the only solution for now):

```
function SortedArray() {
    var arr = [];
    arr.push.apply(arr, arguments);
    arr.__proto__ = SortedArray.prototype;
    return arr;
}
SortedArray.prototype = Object.create(Array.prototype);

SortedArray.prototype.push = function() {
    this.arr.push(arguments);
};
```

Comment: Curious why someone wouldn't? JS has changed.

Answer (score 6):

You could do it this way:

```
arr = []
arr.push = function(data) {
  alert(data); //callback

  return Array.prototype.push.call(this, data);
}
```

If you're in a situation without call, you could also go for this solution:

```
arr.push = function(data) {
  alert(data); //callback
  
  //While unlikely, someone may be using "psh" to store something important
  //So we save it.
  var saved = this.psh;
  this.psh = Array.prototype.push;
  var ret = this.psh(data);
  this.psh = saved;
  return ret;
}
```

While I'm telling you how to do it, you might be better served with using a different method that performs the callback and then just calls *push* on the array rather than overriding *push*. You may end up with some unexpected side effects. For instance, *push* appears to be varadic (takes a variable number of arguments, like *printf*), and using the above would break that.

You'd need to do mess with _Arguments() and _ArgumentsLength() to properly override this function. I highly suggest against this route.

Or you could use "arguments", and that'd work too. I still advise against taking this route though.

Comment: Array.prototype.push.call(this, data); wont work as Array can take multiple items.
Array.prototype.push.apply(this, arguments);

Answer (score 6):

Array.prototype.push was introduced in JavaScript 1.2. It is really as simple as this:

```
Array.prototype.push = function() {
    for( var i = 0, l = arguments.length; i < l; i++ ) this[this.length] = arguments[i];
    return this.length;
};
```

You could always add something in the front of that.

Answer (score 1):

There's another, more native method to achieve this: [`Proxy`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Proxy/Proxy/set)

```
const target = [];

const handler = {
  set: function(array, index, value) {
    // Call callback function here

    // The default behavior to store the value
    array[index] = value;

    // Indicate success
    return true;
  }
};

const proxyArray = new Proxy(target, handler);
```

Answer (score 0):

I wanted to call a function **after** the object has been pushed to the array, so I did the following:

```
myArray.push = function() { 
    Array.prototype.push.apply(this, arguments);
    myFunction();
    return myArray.length;
};

function myFunction() {
    for (var i = 0; i < myArray.length; i++) {
        //doSomething;
    }
}
```