# How to fire a event for Array push? [Flash]

Tags: flash, arrays, events, actionscript, addeventlistener

How would I go about as to addEventListener for a array object.

I'm trying to avoid running a timer every x milliseconds to check for new elements in array object, rather trying to make a event fire when new elements are detected to process them and remove them.

Is it possible with Arrays? maybe ArrayCollections? either is fine.

P.S.> This is **Flash** question **not** javascript

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not create your own array class that extends Array and implements the IEventDispatcher, override the push() function and make it dispatch an event when the function is called?

So something like:

```
package
{
    import flash.events.EventDispatcher;
    import flash.events.IEventDispatcher;

    public class MyArray extends Array implements IEventDispatcher
    {
        public static var ARRAY_PUSHED:String = "MYARRAY_ARRAY_PUSHED";

        private var dispatcher:EventDispatcher;

        public function MyArray(...parameters)
        {
            super(parameters);
            dispatcher = new EventDispatcher(this);
        }

        override public function push(...parameters):uint
        {
            dispatchEvent(ARRAY_PUSHED);
            super.push(parameters);
        }

        public function addEventListener(type:String, listener:Function, useCapture:Boolean = false, priority:int=0, useWeakReference:Boolean=false):void
        {
            dispatcher.addEventListener(type, listener, useCapture, priority);
        }
        public function dispatchEvent(e:Event):Boolean
        {
            return dispatcher.dispatchEvent(e);
        }
        public function hasEventListener(type:String):Boolean
        {
            return dispatcher.hasEventListener(type);
        }
        public function removeEventListener(type:String, listener:Function, useCapture:Boolean=false):void
        {
            dispatcher.removeEventListener(type, listener, useCapture);
        }
        public function willTrigger(type:String):Boolean
        {
            return dispatcher.willTrigger(type);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: well this fails, the event pased to the listeners do not point to de array that dispath the event, and the code is far of working

Answer (score 0):

How about extending the `Array.prototype.push` method? Stolen from [How to extend Array.prototype.push()?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/572604/javascript-how-to-extend-array-prototype-push)

```
Array.prototype.push=(function(){
    var original = Array.prototype.push;
    return function() {
        //Do what you want here.
        return original.apply(this,arguments);
    };
})();
```

Throw any code that you want inside of the inner function body.

Comment: yes thats good to know. Doubt I'll do this in javascript though looking for flash/actionscript advise on this matter

Comment: Can't you override it in Actionscript though? Since the core of AS is ECMAScript.

Comment: seems like you may have found the best answer :P

Answer (score 0):

found

```
 AS3 override function push(...args):uint
    {
        for (var i:* in args)
        {
            if (!(args[i] is dataType))
            {
                args.splice(i,1);
            }
        }
        return (super.push.apply(this, args));
    }
```

with meder's help

Comment: Although I cannot really use this as this overrides the whole push system for array object but i have different array's doing push I just want to target one of them.

Answer (score 0):

```
   private var myArray:Array;

   private function addToArray(element:Object):void
   {
        myArray.push(element);
        dispatch( new Event("Element added));
   }
```

or in a static function if you wanted to call this from another class

```
   public static function addToArray( array:Array , element:Object , dispatcher:EventDispatcher):Array
   {
       array.push(element);
       dispatcher.dispatch( new Event('Added Element') );
       return array;
   }
```

The implementation really depends on your environment.