# Javascript Array prototype

Tags: javascript

Since Array.prototype itself is an array([])  [reference here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/isArray),if we have to replace native prototype how can we place literal object instead we need to place literal array isn't it?

```
Array.prototype=[]
```

Comment: You should never _replace_ a native prototype, and you should almost never modify a native prototype.

Comment: The word "literal" just describes the syntax used to create the object. If you do `[]` or `new Array()`, you're getting the same thing. So if you were to do this, you could use either syntax... though I'm sure you won't want to actually do this.

Answer (score 2):

There's no point in assigning a new array to `Array.prototype`. It's usually a read-only property and the assignment will fail silently.

```
> a = []
[]
> a === Array.prototype
false
> Array.prototype = a
[]
> a === Array.prototype
false
```

Even if the assignment were to succeed, the replacement array would of necessity have been created with the original prototype in place. Thus, the original prototype would be the `[[prototype]]` of the new prototype object and all the native methods would still be found in the prototype chain of any array created after the assignment.

If you want to replace (hide) a native instance method of `Array` (e.g., `push`), just assign the new method to the appropriate property:

```
Array.prototype.push = . . .;
```

Also, see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/572631/535871) for how you might extend a native method (such as `push`). (Unless you're just extending a native method in some way, I can't imagine a use case where this is anything other than a really bad thing to do. Even then...)

Answer (score 2):

EcmaScript 5, the latest version of JavaScript, changed the meaning of

```
[]
```

from

```
 new Array()
```

to create using the original `Array` constructor instead of looking up the name `Array` in scope as earlier versions of JavaScript did.

[The EcmaScript 5 specification](http://es5.github.io/#x11.1.4) says

> ## 11.1.4 Array Initialiser
>
> ...
>
> The production *ArrayLiteral : [ Elision<sub>opt</sub> ]* is evaluated as follows:
>
> 1. Let array be the result of creating a new object as if by the expression `new Array()` **where `Array` is the standard built-in constructor with that name.**

The bolded text is new in EcmaScript 5, and means that the meaning of `[]` is not affected by any subsequent modifications to the `Array` global or its members including its prototype.