# Javascript intercept array set value

Tags: javascript, arrays, prototype, interceptor, defineproperty

Is there a way to intercept or override the array setter? For example:

```
var array = [];
array[2] = 10;
var myInterceptor = function(index, newVal) {
    do stuff when the array value at index is changed.
}
```

So I want myInterceptor to be called when the second line is executed.
I am hoping to find a way to do it with Object.defineProperty()

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, it's [not possible to override the `[]` accessor for javascript arrays](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1711357/how-would-you-overload-the-operator-in-javascript). There are a few other possibilities, though:

1) [Override the `push()` method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/572604/javascript-how-to-extend-array-prototype-push). This is reasonable to do for an individual array instance, but it strongly recommend that you do NOT change `Array.prototype.push`, as that could cause unintended side effects in other portions of javascript code.

2) Add a custom `set()` method. Again, while you *could* add this to the core Array prototype, it's strongly recommended that you do not. Functioning jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/dmillz/RUcBM/

```
arr.set = function (index, value) {
    var oldValue = this[index];
    this[index] = value;
    $.event.trigger("array-change", [this, index, oldValue, value]); // jQuery event trigger, but feel free to use something else besides jQuery    
};
```

3) (Recommended) Create your own observable class that is backed by an array, or simply use a library that provides observable objects, such as [Knockout's Observable Array](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/observableArrays.html), [Ember's Observable](http://emberjs.com/api/classes/Ember.Observable.html), or [Backbone's Model](http://backbonejs.org/#Model)

Answer (score 0):

What you can do is to use the Proxy class to intercept the set method.

```js
var handler = { 
    set: (base,idx,val) => { 
        console.log('values:',base,idx,val); base[idx] = val; 
    } 
};

var mylist = new Proxy([],handler)
mylist[0] = 1
mylist
    > Proxy {0: 1}
Array.isArray(mylist)
    > true
```