# Google analytics, _gaq.push(callback), the callback is never executed

Tags: javascript, iframe, callback, google-analytics, push

I'm using google analytics and tracking data accross iframe, according to the documentation at [enter link description here](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/analyticsjs/cross-domain#iframe)

So in the outer page (containig the iframe) I'm using the `_gaq.push()` method to push and execute a callback that embeds the iframe at runtime.

But that callback is never executed.

Furthermore, in the outer page I have two tracking script, and the callback has to be executed by the second tracking script.

The code that pushes the callback is the following

```
_gaq.push(['ga_code_second_tracking_script._setAccount', '<ga_code_of_second_tracking_script>']);
_gaq.push(function(){
                    console.log('IN PUSH');
                    var tracker = _gat._getTracker('<ga_code_of_second_tracking_script>');
                    embedIframe();                
})
```

Answer (score 0):

You're making a simple mistake of trying to insert a callback function to the push method of `Array.prototype`, which does not exist by default. I mean, `Array.prototype.push()` does not take callback functions. Since `_gaq` is an `Array`, it won't work. What you're doing, is simply adding the function you just defined to the array `_gaq` when you call `_gaq.push(function(){...});` so it does not trigger any function calls. What you can do is define a function yourself [like this person here is trying to do](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/572604/javascript-how-to-extend-array-prototype-push).

For the sake of simplicity, let me add the code here:

```
_gaq.push = function (){
    //Callback Function Call here...
    return Array.prototype.push.apply(this,arguments);
}
```

This method will execute the callback every time you use the `_gaq.push()` function.

You seem to have misunderstood the documentation at Google Developer Docs. It states, `In addition to pushing command arrays, you can also push function objects. This can be especially useful for tracker methods that return values. These functions can reference both _gat and _gaq.` You are only pushing a function object, and not using the function as a callback. Please be clear on this point. And if the function returns any values that should be used by GA, for example, functions that return an array of strings which can be pushed to GA, the return values are pushed.

And just to be sure, you are referring to `analytics.js` in your question (the link for the documentation), while the `_gaq` object is never used in that implementation (`_gaq` is only used in the older `ga.js` implementation).

Even a simple `function(){alert('1');}` executes when pushed to `_gaq`. Again, this is NOT a callback, just a function call executed upon pushing that function.

Comment: it's not true that push doesn't accept callback functions. _gaq object can accept callback functions, according to the documentation https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/gajs/methods/gaJSApi_gaq#_gaq.push

Comment: Are you telling me that even the `console.log` doesn't execute?