# How do I convert use of `arguments` in javascript in Typescript

Tags: javascript, typescript

I have an array. I want to add a method which is called whenever push is called on the array.

How do I write that in typescript?

I have tried:

```
 addEvent(myArray) {
    let _this = this;
    myArray.push = function() {
        Array.prototype.push.apply(myArray, arguments);
        _this.onAddItem(arguments);
    };
}
```

It give a compile time error:  Supplied parameters do not match any signature of call target Expected 0, invoked with two.

I don't understand what it is saying.

Comment: Has ben asked before: [How to extend Array.prototype.push()?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/572604/how-to-extend-array-prototype-push)

Comment: Yes, this is where I got the example.  But I can't get this to work in Typescript.  So my question is how to use in Typescript.

Comment: You arent returning your `apply`. Keep calm and take a more detailed look to the answer in the other post.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of using `arguments`, a more TS approach (and a better ES2015 approach in general) is to use rest parameters.  I'm not exactly sure what you are trying to do, but you can use rest parameters like this:

```
addEvent(myArray) {
   // use an arrow function so you can avoid creating _this
   myArray.push = (...args: any[]) => {
        Array.prototype.push.apply(myArray, args);
        this.onAddItem(arguments);
    };
}
```

Then you can call `addEvent` like this:

```
let arrayLikeObject = new SomeObjecct();
myObj.addEvent(arrayLikeObject);

arrayLikeObject.push(1, 2, 3);
```

But, there's something not quite right about this approach. With TS, you should be providing stricter type annotations on your parameters.  What type is `myArray`? What type of args does it accept? This should be explicitly spelled out. If it turns out that it accepts a wide variety of types, then that would indicate poor design as well.

---

**EDIT**

Now that I know what you are trying to do, I can see that the function declaration should look more like this:

```
    (myArray as any[]).push = (...args: any[]): number => {
        Array.prototype.push.apply(myArray, args);
        this.onAddItem(arguments);
        return myArray.length;
    };
```

Comment: `myArray` is an `Array<any>`

Comment: But I still get the same error compile error on `Array.prototype.push.apply(myArray, args);`

Comment: I just want to get notified when an item is added to the array, so I can decorate the item.

Comment: You should be using `any[]` as the type, then. And the type of push needs to return a number.

Comment: Ok, I added the any[] type.  But I don't understand what you mean by `And the type of push needs to return a number.`

Comment: Array.prototype.push returns the new length of the array. In order to be semantically compatible, your function must do the same. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/push

Comment: Ah I see.  Ok, I tried what you wrote on the Edit, but the second line still gives the same compile error message.

Comment: Maybe it's a typescript issue - the code does compile and produces javascript and it looks ok to me.  It's just in Visual Studio 2015 editor that it shows the error.  I really appreciate you helping me out with this!

Comment: Hmmm...I'm trying that in sublime text with the TS plugin enabled and I'm not getting an error. Maybe the problem has to do with code that you are not showing?

Comment: I don't know the UI issue, but the code works great so I am going to credit you with the answer.  Again, thank you.

Comment: This quieted the compiler:  `(Array.prototype.push as any).apply(myArray, args);`

Comment: It kind of goes against the spirit of TS to use `any` gratuitously. If you can paste a self-contained snippet in a new question, we can figure out why the compiler is complaining.